# Reconstruct object groups from Revit model in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In my Revit model I have groups of objects that I can select when working in Revit. Now, using this model in Forge viewer, I can only select the single elements (or their parent elements in the browser structure), but I cannot reconstruct my groups from Revit.
Is there a possibility, or some proposed workaround?

Comment: Is there a way to get the list of ExternalIDs for the given a AssemblyID ?
 
 
getExternalIdMapping - function gives the list of ids and DBids
i am able to apply the color for the given Element using that dbid, But its not working for the AssemblyDBIds

Answer (score 0):

Do you see those groups in the viewer model browser? For example you get components grouped by Walls, Floors and so on. If the components are grouped by another way, then there is probably no direct way to select them in the viewer.

You would need to establish the mapping yourself, for example you can access the Revit elementId for a given component dbId using `viewer.getProperties(dbid, function(res))` > `res.externalId` is the revit Id. If you store - eg. in a custom DB - your Revit groups along with the list of Revit Ids in each group, then you can map that to the Viewer components dbIds when you load the model. Using the selection event, when you select a component, check in which group it belongs to and select programmatically other components of that group. You could also create a custom UI to visualize that or derive the model browser to show those groups. It requires programming work obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Philippe. The Forge translation process does not have the same notion of groups as Revit. Remember that Forge has to implement mechanisms that are valid for all kinds of different types of CAD seed files. You can implement Philippe's suggestion by retrieving all groups in Revit using the Revit API and a `FilteredElementCollector`, determine their member element and instance ids, and use that information to create the required mapping.